# Limiting the number of processes being run at once by subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a list of computationally intensive files that I'm running using Python's subprocess module. The idea is to use `Popen` rather than something like `check_call` to go through the list more quickly. However, when the list is larger than say 4 or 5 elements the computers, the program saps all of the computers resources making it unusable until its finished. My question is: is there a convenient way to limit the number of processes that my program opens at once?

The code I'm using is simple but part of a larger program so that pasting all code needed to run it is not possible.

```
def run_fast(self):
    '''
    self.cps_dct is a nested dictionary dct[index1][index2]=filename
    CopasiSE is a program for simulating mathematical models using the terminal/cmd

    '''
    for i in self.cps_dct.keys():
        for j in self.cps_dct[i]:
            subprocess.Popen('CopasiSE {}'.format(self.cps_dct[i][j]))
    return self.cps_dct
```

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `multiprocessing.Pool`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to what was suggested by Klaus:
Something like that could work:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess


class Cps:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cps_dct = {
            'a': {
                '1': 'file1',
                '2': 'file2',
                '3': 'file3',
                '4': 'file4'
            },
            'b': {
                '1': 'file1',
                '2': 'file2',
                '3': 'file3',
                '4': 'file4'
            }
        }


def open_proc(file_name):
    subprocess.Popen('CopasiSE {}'.format(file_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    process_cap = 4
    p = Pool(process_cap)
    # Initialize the object.
    item = Cps()
    for i in item.cps_dct.keys():
        iterable = item.cps_dct[i].values()
        p.map(open_proc, iterable)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```